# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target [$concrete] is not instantiable

Tags: php, android, composer-php

i have a problem while running composer update

Target `Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Database` is not instantiable

container code reads

```
protected function notInstantiable($concrete)
    {
        if (! empty($this->buildStack)) {
            $previous = implode(', ', $this->buildStack);

            $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable while building [$previous].";
        } else {
            $message = "Target [$concrete] is not instantiable.";
        }

            throw new BindingResolutionException($message);
    }
```

any solution?

this error happens while running composer update, or any php artisan commands.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, the issue is not with composer but with `firebase-php` go into the commands or php file that has **`use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Database`** and change it to **`use Kreait\Firebase\Database`** 
 i found this fix on the official documentation at [Firebase SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html)